# How to create database table from entity in symfony 2.6

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, entity

what i've done so far is -> i have created a bundle and entity class in it and created a database table named "news" from that entity class using following command

php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force

everything went well.

now i created a new bundle and an other entity class in it from which i want to create an other table in database named "user" but gives an error that "The table with name 'symfony.news' already exists' ".

```
class user { 
   private $id; 
   private $userEmail; 

   public function getId() { 
       return $this->id; 
   } 

   public function setUserEmail($userEmail) { 
       $this->userEmail = $userEmail; 
       return $this; 
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Your entity doesn't contain annotations, and doctrine have no idea what to do with this entity. But if you add to you entity something like:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    public function getId()
    { 
        return $this->id; 
    } 

    public function setUserEmail($userEmail)
    { 
        $this->userEmail = $userEmail; 
        return $this; 
    }
}
```

**OR**

if you add file: `User.orm.xml` like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
  <entity name="AppBundle\Entity\User" table="user">
    <unique-constraints>
      <unique-constraint name="UNIQ_797E6294E7927C74" columns="email"/>
    </unique-constraints>
    <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
      <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
    </id>
    <field name="email" type="string" column="email" length="60" nullable="false"/>
  </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

to your `Resources/config/doctrine/` directory,
you'll be able to run command:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

and as result you'll receive:

```
Updating database schema...
Database schema updated successfully! "1" queries were executed
```

Truly believe that it will solve your problem...

Answer (score 8):

For symfony 4 and 4++:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

For symfony 3:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Comment: php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
Above Line also works with symfony 5.2

Comment: yes Symfony 4 and 4++ : .php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force

Comment: If you only need the SQL, **not actually migrate through PHP** - **`php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql`** *"Instead of trying to apply generated SQLs into EntityManager Storage Connection, output them"* docs: `bin/console help doctrine:schema:create` (works in doctrine/orm 2.13)

Answer (score 0):

If neither *"php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force"* nor *"php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force"* (you probably work on windows..) is working out, you may try:

**"php artisan doctrine:schema:update --force"**.

Only thing worked out for me.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use doctrine command?

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entity
```

Comment: i did just like u said but it only create entity not table in database..
this  command app/console doctrine:schema:update --force creates table in db but the problem is that how can i tell this command to read all entity files in all bundles and skip if the table already exists otherwise create that table..

this command works perfectly when run first time

Comment: doctrine:schema:update will update all tables. If the table exists, then it will check for any column changes, but it won't recreate the table.

Comment: In addition, you cannot leave old tables unmodified if you have changed something in the metadata (column definitions, relations, etc.). So doctrine:schema:update it's safe as long as you don't do modifications on older entities, but only adding new ones.